# Don't have access to index.html on apache?

Tags: php, apache, permissions, redhat, httpd.conf

I'm running Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server (I think). When I ssh in and run grep apache, there's no output. But...another file (index.php, read below) on the same machine/ip/directory is showing.

I'm actually taking over for someone. Site/pages are kept at /var/www/html. In that directory there are index.php and index.html. I was able to reach both.

I changed index.html to welcome page and uploaded and replaced the old one. When attempting to reach index.html from another computer, I recieve the following:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
```

But I can still reach index.php in the same directory. In case it matters, I used 'cp' copy index.html from another directory into /var/www/html.

I'm pretty new to this. Can someone clue me in? Thanks!

Comment: If you have both a .php and a .html, one would have more importance than the other, depending on your `.htaccess` file. In an ideal world, you wouldn't have more than one index file, no matter the extension, to avoid such issues. However, maybe this could help you: `DirectoryIndex index.html`

Comment: Verify that the User / Group Owner of the index.html matches that of the index.php, as well as the file permissions. If they don't make them match.

Comment: @PubliDesign Yeah, I agree you should only have one. But the point is that both original files could be viewed. Since replacing index.html with my own index.html, that file can no longer be viewed.

Comment: @Welsh Running "ls -l" shows exact same permissions, owner, and group.

Comment: Then, consider index.html and home.html, or any other name; to view them both, change the name. The other option would be to have a link to "/" which is defined by the DirectoryIndex (say index.php) and have one to index.html, which is a regular page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem was but...

When I used a text editor besides text wrangler, it worked.

When I created all the folders on the server and moved the files to the folders individually, it worked.